# mysql check a calculated column is greater than an arbitrary value

Tags: sql, mysql

As the title states I was wondering how to check the value of a calculated column is greater than an arbitrary value.

I have just finished a mock exam for Uni (I can't repeat it) and the last question stumped me.

For context the question was:

"Write a query to show the ‘Total selling values’ realised by each staff member that has sales of more than 500,000. Consider in the total for one staff member all the orders from the clients that have that staff member as sales representative. The SQL query should display the staff number, ‘Staff name’ (concatenating first and last name), job title and ‘Total selling value’ as calculated column (the sum of all products between price per each item and quantity ordered) and the results should be sorted descending by the total selling value."

With the query being written in mysql on a database supplied by the tutor.

AFAIAA I got everything queried properly but when I tried to check if the calculated column was > 500,000 I either got an error or a table with no rows depending on how I tried to deal with it

I tried two different ways.

The first attempt:

```
   SELECT s.staffNo, concat(s.firstName, ' ', s.lastName) AS 'Staff name', s.jobTitle,
   COUNT(od.orderNumber) * (od.priceEach * od.quantityOrdered) AS 'Total selling values'  
   FROM rstaff s, rclients c, rorderdetails od, rpurchaseorders po
   WHERE s.staffNo = c.salesRepStaffNo
   AND c.clientNumber = po.clientNumber
   AND po.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
   AND COUNT(od.orderNumber) * (od.priceEach * od.quantityOrdered) > 500000
   GROUP BY s.staffNo
   ORDER BY 'Total selling values' DESC
```

This gave me an error based on grouping (revolving around the second COUNT call).

The second attempt:

```
    SELECT s.staffNo, concat(s.firstName, ' ', s.lastName) AS 'Staff name', s.jobTitle,
    COUNT(od.orderNumber) * (od.priceEach * od.quantityOrdered) AS 'Total selling values'  
    FROM rstaff s, rclients c, rorderdetails od, rpurchaseorders po
    WHERE s.staffNo = c.salesRepStaffNo
    AND c.clientNumber = po.clientNumber
    AND po.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
    AND 'Total selling values' > 500000
    GROUP BY s.staffNo
    ORDER BY 'Total selling values' DESC
```

Gave me an empty table.

If I changed the line
`AND 'Total selling values' > 500000`
To
`AND 'Total selling values' < 500000`
I got the same result as when I removed the line, which is all of the staff with total sales ranging from ~300,000 : ~1,000,000

Just a bit confused as to why this is the case, tbh.
I'm pretty new to SQL in general and I am actively studying.

To reiterate, I cannot retake this mock exam so I'm not looking for answers for homework or anything.

Comment: 'Total selling values' > 500000  compares a string to 500000 that is wrong, you need to use HAVING and use backtips for columns

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In SQL, you can't reference a column alias in the WHERE clause of the query where that column was defined. It may seem counter-intuitive that the clauses of an SQL statement are not evaluated from top to bottom. The conditions in the WHERE clause are evaluated row-by-row, filtering out many rows. Later, expressions in the select-list are evaluated.

This is a good thing, because the select-list is not evaluated for rows that won't be part of the result set. So it's for the sake of avoiding wasting a lot of computing.

Nor can you use aggregate functions like `COUNT()` or `SUM()` in the WHERE clause, because the expression of a WHERE clause is evaluated for only one row at a time, not the aggregation of many rows in a group.

You can use the HAVING clause to make a condition that applies to the whole group. In MySQL, you can reference aliases in the HAVING clause, because HAVING is evaluated after the select-list has done its work.

```
SELECT s.staffNo, 
 CONCAT(s.firstName, ' ', s.lastName) AS `Staff name`,
 s.jobTitle,
 COUNT(od.orderNumber) * (od.priceEach * od.quantityOrdered) AS `Total selling values`  
FROM rstaff s
JOIN rclients c ON s.staffNo = c.salesRepStaffNo
JOIN rpurchaseorders po ON  po.orderNumber = od.orderNumber
JOIN rorderdetails od ON c.clientNumber = po.clientNumber
GROUP BY s.staffNo
HAVING `Total selling values` > 500000
ORDER BY `Total selling values` DESC
```

I fixed the use of back-ticks around your column aliases. Single-quotes are for strings, and in MySQL back-ticks are for identifiers (e.g. table names, column names, etc.).

If you're learning SQL in modern times, you should learn proper JOIN syntax (shown above), which became standard in 1992! Don't use the outdated comma-style join syntax.

Comment: Just wanted to say thanks for your help. I ended up scoring 99/100 on my exam. Very happy